# Seeking software to visualize and export area selected in OSM format?

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations

I have a very large OSM file and I would like to know if there is software that can open the OSM file and then when I select a certain area to be able to export it in OSM file again. I found [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/) and [Marble](https://marble.kde.org/) but both of them can't export area in OSM format.

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis can subset by bounding boxes, amongst other capabilities. Its command line though - no visualisation. There are some front ends GUIs, but they tend to be workflow rather than visualising the source data.

Comment: Thank you BradHards for your help. Ive tried it and it work!

Comment: So you don't need the visualise the areas? I'll turn the comment into an answer, so you can mark it "done" below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) can subset by bounding boxes, amongst other capabilities. Its command line though - no visualisation. There are some front ends GUIs, but they tend to be workflow rather than visualising the source data.

Answer (score 1):

For [splitting OSM files into different geographical regions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Splitting_one_big_file_into_different_geographical_regions) there are various tools available, for example osmium, osmosis and osmconvert.

For visualization/rendering you can take a look at the [client-side GUI applications](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering#Client-side_GUI_applications), for example Kosmtik and Maperitive.